# Limiting the number of rows in a web page

Tags: python, html, django

I have developed one SaaS based application on Django. During searching more than thousand rows from the database are loaded in to the web page. I want to limit the number of rows in a web page, I mean if there is more than 100 rows, then i need to display it on the next page (like Google).

Anybody can help me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/

Comment: You can start by marking this one as accepted. Sheesh, and you were just reminded by @RikPoggi